# Lost my canada refusal letter

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, lost-documents

Recently my student visa for Canada was refused and I lost the refusal letter. I paid 25% of the fee to the college. Now they are asking for refusal letter to initiate the refund process. Please help me with this situation. It’s a huge amount. If I don’t get it back it will be a big problem for me. Please help to get the letter.

Answer (score 3):

Some lost, damaged and destroyed documents can be replaced through the Canadian Immigration web site:

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=045&top=12

I'm not sure if this applies to refusal letters.

It's also possible to [request information](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/transparency/access-information-privacy/requests-information-act.html) held by Immigration, Refugees, and Citizenship Canada (IRCC), who won't be able to reproduce the letter, but should be able to confirm your status. You have to be in Canada to make a request, but your college could request this.

Comment: Don't privacy rules preclude the college from getting that data from the IRCC directly?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Perhaps, but I'm sure that between the OP, the college, and the IRCC they can find a way to deal with that.